# Heroku Deploy Fails: pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'Version'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, pip

Unsure why my herokuapp is failing to deploy. I am building a flask application on python 3.6.5. My application runs on a local server perfectly fine. The application deployed correctly on python 3.6.4 two months ago but I was given a warning to upgrade to 3.6.5. Under both 3.6.4 and 3.6.5, my application crashed with this error. Is this an error with the heroku-18 stack? I checked out https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/680 but didn't know how it quite helped me. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.69 KiB | 1.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.5
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Invalid requirement: 'Package          Version'
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 92, in __init__
remote:            req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1617, in parseString
remote:            raise exc
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1607, in parseString
remote:            loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
remote:            loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
remote:            loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
remote:            loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3164, in parseImpl
remote:            raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
remote:        pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 17), (line:1, col:18)
remote:        
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
remote:            req = Requirement(req)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
remote:            requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
remote:        pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'Version'"
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to weborg.
```

requirements.txt:

```
Package          Version
---------------- -------
alembic          0.9.9  
click            6.7    
Flask            1.0.2  
Flask-Admin      1.5.1  
Flask-Login      0.4.1  
Flask-Migrate    2.1.1  
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2  
Flask-Uploads    0.2.1  
Flask-WTF        0.14.2 
gunicorn         19.8.1 
itsdangerous     0.24   
Jinja2           2.10   
Mako             1.0.7  
MarkupSafe       1.0    
phonenumbers     8.9.6  
pip              10.0.1 
psycopg2         2.7.4  
python-dateutil  2.7.3  
python-editor    1.0.3  
setuptools       39.2.0 
six              1.11.0 
SQLAlchemy       1.2.8  
Werkzeug         0.14.1 
wheel            0.31.1 
WTForms          2.1
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.5
```

procfile

```
web: flask db upgrade; flask translate compile; gunicorn webapp:app
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `requirements.txt` is not in the correct format.

It seems to me that you have generated it using `pip list`. You want to use `pip freeze` when generating your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Hehe. Feel free to accept an answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Format of your `requirements.txt` is rather strange. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip for a proper format example. Detailed docs are at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Comment: You're right thank you! I used pip list instead of pip freeze by accident